# Android install self signed Certificate SSL from device settings VS programmatically install

Tags: java, android, ssl, soap

I have followed [this guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826045/Android-security-Implementation-of-Self-signed-SSL#_comments) in generating self signed SSL certificate, 
and I successfully made the .cer and .bks. However:

Is installing the .cer file using the device settings the same as installing the .bks file using CODE?

I'm having an issue where my phone browser accepts my website with no issues. However, when I run my app to query soap request from a service of same `website/myservice.ASMX` it gives  'Hostname was not verified' and if using trustmaster "accept all host and certificates" I get error 405

Code Accessing the website:

```
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, method);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    PropertyInfo password = new PropertyInfo();
    password.setName(ID);
    password.setValue(pass);
    password.setType(String.class);
    Request.addProperty(password);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpsTransport = new HttpTransportSE("https://"+MAIN_REQUEST_URL+":"+sPORT+SERVICELOCATION);
    makeFileOffline(androidHttpsTransport.getHost() +"\n"+ SERVICELOCATION,"AgriHTTP" );
     try {

        //FakeX509TrustManager.allowAllSSL();<< When enabled it gives 405 

        androidHttpsTransport.call(NAMESPACE+method, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        String webServiceResult = resultsString.toString();


    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.d(e.toString(),"LogCat" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `Log.d(e.toString(),"LogCat" );` should be `Log.e("LogCat", e.getMessage(), e);` more info :  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)

Comment: Consider using volley to make api requests. here is the guide to do that, https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The certificate installed by Settings can be seen by the Android device itself and any apps Google, or the System made. But your app can not see the certificate, this is why you need to import or install it via code in your own app.